# PHP script not executing

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have a form with 1222 fields (I know the number is large, but it's a form for saving translations). When I submit the form, the script is not executing. I get no error message and the error log is empty. Even if the script I post to contains only an echo command, nothing is executed and all I see is a blank page.

I am quite sure this is a PHP setting problem, as the form can be submitted without any problems on other servers. Can anyone shed some light on what the issue could be?

The HTML is:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="account-form-282f96c7d1ed98d24606d209dcad9842" value=""/>
    <!-- 1221 more inputs with different names, but format is the same as above -->
    <input type="submit" name="submitBT" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
echo(1);
?>
```

Edit 1:
If I simplify the input names, e.g.: input_1, input_2 etc. the submit works fine.

Edit 2: 
I noticed I receive a 406 Not Acceptable HTTP response.

Comment: Show code please, and be sure `error_reporting` is turned on.

Comment: What if you increase `post_max_size` in php.ini?

Comment: Check `phpinfo()`, PHP by default has a limit of 1,000 inputs. The setting is called MAX_INPUT_VARS. You can raise the limit in php.ini.

Comment: @phpisuber01 Would suggest to post this as an answer. Didn't know about this

Comment: Debug your code: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1409082)

Comment: MAX_INPUT_VARS is 2000

Comment: Post_max_size is 128M

Comment: If apache sent you an error code then it should have logged it as well.

Comment: I checked all logs:error_log, modsec_debug_log, modsec_audit_log, suexec_log, suphp_log and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with mod_security, for some reason it didn't like the submitted data and stopped the execution of the script.